# Thread safe file writing in PHP

Tags: php, multithreading

I need to log when and who uses one of my application.

For that, the actual simple solution would be to contact a server and write a log. I have a LAMP server hosting my project website. I'm not a php/web developer.

I'm afraid about concurrent writings, what if two of my clients download the log page at the same time ? Are the php fopen/fwrite/fclose methods thread safe ?

Comment: have you thing about saving logs in a database?

Comment: In my company we save everything the user do. Make a file with the database info "you can use another db". and use it on every page or button

Comment: @RafaelShkembi: It would be easier for me to log in a file but if you think the only thread safe solution would be to log in a db, then I'll move for the db solution.

Comment: you can try olso to copy the script on another server, i mean make a cronjob that copies the file to a different server and after the copy you can delete the file. I believe he best solution is the database, it's your call :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lock the log file around the logging function:

```
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);
fwrite($fh, $message);
flock($fh, LOCK_UN);
```